# Is it possible to bind the inline style with vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am curious, is it possible to bind the inline style in Vue.js? I'm familiar with class binding but what if sometimes for some reason you want to bind a style statement inline, is it possible to bind it like you do with class?

For example:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <h1 :style="{('background:red') : condition}"> Text </h1>
      <button @click='condition = true'>Click me</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      condition: false,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

In the example above I'd like to change the background of the element when the condition becomes true.

Answer (score 8):

Of course it is possible as described here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

```
<template>
  <div>
      <h1 v-bind:style="{ color: activeColor, fontSize: fontSize + 'px' }"> Text </h1>
      <button @click='condition = true'>Click me</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script> 
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      condition: false,
      activeColor: 'white',
      fontSize: 12,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's possible please go through the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

**Note**: please use `computed`, `methods` instead of inline for better debugging

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 :style="styleObject"> Text </h1>
    <button @click='toggleCondition'>Click me</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      condition: false,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    styleObject() {
      return this.condition ? { background: 'red' } : {};
    },
  },
  methods: {
    toggleCondition() {
      this.condition = !this.condition;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tnx, I'm still a bit new to vue so didn't go through all the docs and needed this real quick. You and Thomas made this very clear to me!