# Vue component not being rendered with props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am beginner in Vue. I created a custom component and tried to bind everything exactly as shown in the starter Vue cli template. Here is the code.

Circle.vue

```html
<template>
    <div :style="custom">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name:'Circle',
    props:{
        size:String,
        color:String
    },
    computed:{
        custom(){
            return {
                background:this.color,
                height:this.size,
                width:this.size
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

inside my View.vue file

```js
<script>
// :class="['']"
import Circle from '@/components/Circle.vue'
export default {
  name: "Landing",
  components:{
    Circle
  }
};
</script>
```

I tried to use it so

```html
<Circle size="100px" color="#222222"/>
```

I tried printing the props as it is but it also doesnt work

```html
<template>
    <div :style="custom">
        {{size}} {{color}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Nothing is being shown on the screen after I do this. I took help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54513103/is-it-possible-to-bind-the-inline-style-with-vue-js)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Check in your console for any errors

Comment: console is fine. The web page is also fine. But my component is not rendered, which means everything is binded properly but something still doesnt work

Comment: The issue appears to be with the names `View` and `Circle`. If I take your example and run it in CodeSandbox, I see errors reported ~ _"Do not use built-in or reserved HTML elements as component id: View"_. Same for `Circle`. These are both [SVG elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element)

Comment: Change your components to `components: { "component-name": Circle }` and then use it in your template like this: `<component-name />`

Comment: Use vue dev tools to inspect and debug you vue components. You can see if your components are properly rendered or the data and computed properties are correct or not

If you use chrome then https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#:%7E:text=Component%20names%20should%20always%20be,elements%20are%20a%20single%20word.):

> Component names should always be multi-word, except for root `App` components, and built-in components provided by Vue, such as `<transition>` or `<component>`.
>
> This prevents conflicts with existing and future HTML elements, since all HTML elements are a single word.

You have two options when defining component names:

**With kebab-case**

```
Vue.component('my-circle', { /* ... */ })
```

When defining a component with kebab-case, you must also use kebab-case when referencing its custom element, such as in `<my-circle>`.

**With PascalCase**

```
Vue.component('MyCircle', { /* ... */ })
```

When defining a component with PascalCase, you can use either case when referencing its custom element. That means both `<my-circle>` and `<MyCircle>` are acceptable.

**Demo:**

```js
Vue.component('my-circle', {
  props: {
    size: String,
    color: String
  },
  template: '<div :style="custom"></div>',
  computed: {
    custom() {
      return {
        background: this.color,
        height: this.size,
        width: this.size
      }
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#myApp"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="myApp">
  <my-circle size="100px" color="#222222" />
</div>
```

Comment: Yes changing the name does work.

Comment: How did you answer this 4 mins after it was closed?

Comment: Not sure how that happened, but I had already started composing the answer before it was closed, so that might be a bug or something.